# User-friendly xml parsing libarary for c/c++ application supporting default values for attributes not specified

Tags: library, c++

I am looking for user friendly library for parsing an xml file. Minimal requirement is I should be able to get default value of attribute if it is not present, with support to extract c++ data types such as boolean. I do not find libxml++ very user friendly, while tinyXML2 is almost Looks like What I am looking for, but it does not support default values and boolean value extraction.

So APIs should look like:

```
size = element.getAttrAsInt("size", 100); //if sizeis not specified return 100
price = element.getAttrAsDouble("price", 11.1); //if price is not specified return 11.1
```

Comment: You may want to look at [`pugixml`](http://pugixml.org/) recommended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042855/boost-and-xml-c). I think it covers the [attribute handling](http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#access.attrdata) you are searching for.

Comment: @Florian: thanks a lot. This seems to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

You may want to look at [`pugixml`](http://pugixml.org/) (recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042855/boost-and-xml-c)):

> pugixml is a light-weight C++ XML processing library. It features:
>
> - DOM-like interface with rich traversal/modification capabilities
> - Extremely fast non-validating XML parser which constructs the DOM tree from an XML file/buffer
> - XPath 1.0 implementation for complex data-driven tree queries
> - Full Unicode support with Unicode interface variants and automatic encoding conversions
>
> The library is extremely portable and easy to integrate and use.

It does cover the [attribute handling](http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#access.attrdata) you are searching for:

> pugixml provides several accessors that convert attribute value to
>   some other type:
>
> ```
> int          xml_attribute::as_int(int def = 0) const; 
> unsigned int xml_attribute::as_uint(unsigned int def = 0) const; 
> double       xml_attribute::as_double(double def = 0) const; 
> float        xml_attribute::as_float(float def = 0) const; 
> bool         xml_attribute::as_bool(bool def = false) const; 
> long long    xml_attribute::as_llong(long long def = 0) const;
> unsigned long long xml_attribute::as_ullong(unsigned long long def = 0) const;
> ```

Comment: @Floarian: thanks, this is the answer. I have started using it.